# cfimage from binary in cfdocument

Tags: coldfusion, cfdocument, cfimage

I am writing a PDF dynamically, and am creating a QR code on the document for eTicketing purposes

i set my cfdocument localurl=yes to include a different image, which works fine, but since I am using an API call to get the binary for the qrCode, the using cfimage to display the image, it is only showing a red X

```
<cfdocument format="PDF"  overwrite="Yes" localUrl="yes" pageType = "letter">
<body>
<cfoutput>
<section id="header">

<img src="file:///#ExpandPath('images/header.png')#"/>
<cfimage action="writeToBrowser" source="#rc.qrCode#" />
</cfoutput>
</body>
</html>
</cfdocument>
```

the source variable rc.qrCode is a binary response that works perfectly until i place inside cfdocument, it generates a url like this `http://mysite/CFFileServlet/_cf_image/_cfimg-7945382145198648283.PNG` as image source

i am sure this has todo with localurl and file:///, i just an not knowledgable enough to know why

Answer (score 0):

Do not need to use physical path rather use relative path to your page.
e.g.
If you code in index.cfm of root folder and image inside images folder

try <img src="images/header.png"> , Note that it should not start with root path rather relative to your file.

**UPDATE**

writetoBrowser internally write file to hard drive to it's temporary location (topically, C:\ColdFusion10\cfusion\tmpCache\CFFileServlet) and while rendering it to browser it use relative path like "/CFFileServlet/_cf_image/_cfimg1592404668342998556.PNG", you can say that ColdFusion internally map CFFileServlet directory with all coldfusion site but notice leading forward slash and this makes issue with localurl=true. Since localurl=true either need physical path or relative path to your document.

Good idea is instead of writetobrowser you can write same image to harddrive at your location and give physical path in img tag. I do not this there will any performance issue since ColdFusion internally doing same thing when you are using writetobrowser attribute :)

Comment: The issue isnt with the images/header.png, its with using the cfimage tag to translate binary to an image, which creates a temp file on the CfFileservlet

Comment: Sorry, I have misread your question. I have updated my answer.